# Invalid column name when same DateDiff is used before without problem

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT 
    firstname, lastname, datetake, DateReturn,
    DATEDIFF(DAY, DateTake, DateReturn) AS Delay
FROM 
    dbo.ReaderCard, dbo.Orders, dbo.Literature
WHERE 
    dbo.ReaderCard.CardID = dbo.Orders.CardID
    AND dbo.Literature.ItemID = dbo.Orders.ItemID

IF DATEDIFF(DAY, DateTake, DateReturn) > 60
    SELECT (DATEDIFF(DAY, DateTake, DateReturn) * 1.5) AS FineSum
    FROM dbo.Orders
```

I keep getting an error "invalid column name" on `datetake` and `datereturn` in the IF (not the select in the if) and I can't figure out how to fix it. Please give me something...

Comment: Well if you said `SELECT * FROM sys.databases; IF name = 'bob'...` wouldn't you wonder how SQL Server read your mind to figure out where `name` was supposed to come from? The `IF` is a _different_ statement. It has no idea what tables or columns you've referenced in other statements.

Comment: Old style comma joins are not best practice, I recommend using explicit joins.

Comment: First off, if you are using a standalone if statement you will need to use a local variable i.e. @DateTake. Also if your first select returns more than row, it is undefined which row value you would use.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're just after a `CASE` expression in the `SELECT`, which you'll need to do *in the same statement* because SQL Server has no memory in the `IF` statement what you might have referenced in some other statement:

```
SELECT firstname, lastname, datetake, DateReturn
    , Delay = CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY,DateTake,DateReturn) > 60
THEN 1.5 ELSE 1.0 END * DATEDIFF(DAY,DateTake,DateReturn)
FROM dbo.ReaderCard, dbo.Orders, dbo.Literature
WHERE dbo.ReaderCard.CardID = dbo.Orders.CardID
AND dbo.Literature.ItemID = dbo.Orders.ItemID;
```

But also you should be using proper `INNER JOIN` syntax, this `FROM tbl, tbl, tbl` form was out of style in the 90s, [for good reason](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins):

```
-- Prefix all these columns with the alias!
SELECT firstname, lastname, datetake, DateReturn
    , Delay = CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY,DateTake,DateReturn) > 60
THEN 1.5 ELSE 1.0 END * DATEDIFF(DAY,DateTake,DateReturn)
FROM dbo.ReaderCard AS rc
  INNER JOIN dbo.Orders AS o
          ON rc.CardID = o.CardID
  INNER JOIN dbo.Literature AS l
          ON l.ItemID = o.ItemID;
```

Comment: Well I'm kind of the master of inefficient code, but thank you very much!

Comment: @T-rEGGs The old-style join issue is less about efficiency and more about correctness (or at least the risk of incorrectness).